# TypeScript Datatype for List of Record

Tags: javascript, angularjs, generics, typescript, immutable.js

I'm using Immutable JS with TypeScript in my Angular 2 project. What I'm trying to achieve is create a variable as a List of a Record

```
export const SuggestionRecord = Record({
  accountName: '',
  accountSubName: '',
  accountImgUrl: '',
});
```

and I'm using it to specify the type of an Input Property like this:

```
  @Input() suggestionsData: List<Record<string, any>>;
```

Unfortunately, I can't use `SuggestionRecord` inside the List generic brackets as.

```
  @Input() suggestionsData: List<SuggestionRecord>;
```

Is there a way I can achieve the same? Because, it sucks if I have to remain dependent on `Record<string, any>`. I want my input property to be type safe.

Comment: why can't you use `  @Input() suggestionsData: List<SuggestionRecord>;`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `typeof` inside the type parameter:

```
suggestionsData: List<typeof SuggestionRecord>;
```